# I-Bus widget visible after reboot although unchecked

Tags: ibus

The I-Bus widget is always on the panel after reboot although Preferences-Show icon on system tray is unchecked.

How to fix it?[image]

I noticed it after upgrading Ubuntu from 20 to 22

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu Core that is the only product where the version is 20 and or 22.

Comment: @David sorry, I don't understand. The command lsb_release -a gives me the following output:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

I also use KDE

Comment: Yes and your question said just 20 please update the question.

Comment: @David English isn't my mother language, but I thought that it was clear that the problem became apparent after the upgrade to version 22.